# Can't install Ubuntu from USB on Intel Mac OSX 10.4

Tags: system-installation, macosx

I am trying to install Ubuntu on Intel Mac Osx 10.4. I followed all the instructions provided on Ubuntu forums. I also installed refit on my mac.

But after I restart the computer and go into the refit menu, I just see boot legacy OS options, and do not see any option for booting from the USB drive I created.

I am reading here that it the USB needs grub2 and so on but if there is anything extra needed it should be part of the clear instruction process. I have spent two frustrating days trying to install Ubuntu, and it certainly is not motivating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Linux on old Mac X 10.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206403/how-to-install-linux-on-old-mac-x-10-4)

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Mac running Mavericks and I installed Ubuntu on it without using refit. Make sure the USB you are using is a bootable USB. I used a bootable DVD to do my installation, just because its much easier to create a bootable DVD using disk utility. Here are the steps I used: (This method worked for me, I am currently using Ubuntu to answer this question and do programming on it)

```
   1. Use disk utility to make a free disk space partition of how much ever space you
      want to provide for your Ubuntu. 
   2. Once you make the partition, you want to insert the DVD or USB into the macbook
      and restart your computer.
   3. On startup, hold down the 'alt' button on your macbook to get to the boot menu.
   4. Choose the boot DVD or USB and it should take you to the installation process.
   5. Once you go through the pick you language step, you should get an option
      asking if you want to install Ubuntu along side mac OS, remove your current OS
      and install Ubuntu, or custom.
   6. Choose whichever you want, whether you want to run it alongside or just have 
      Ubuntu and remove Mac OS completely. That's your choice.
   7. From there just follow the steps and you should be good, it will update and
      when it restarts you will see the menu to boot from Ubuntu, or if you chose to
      run alongside mac, to boot from mac. (Quick Tip: If you choose to boot mac,
      don't choose mac from the boot menu whenever your laptop turns on. Just hit
      'esc' and type 'exit' and hit 'enter', that should boot in Mac OS then. If you want to boot in
      Ubuntu just leave it alone and it will automatically boot into Ubuntu.)
```

*** Do remember to BACK UP YOUR MACBOOK before trying to install Ubuntu on your Mac since it is very tricky and kind of risky. If something goes wrong you can always boot back into Mac and install Mavericks again. Shouldn't lose anything but its always best to Backup! Remember it is TRICKY and RISKY so if you try this... Pay attention to what you do and try at your own risk.***

Comment: I have a old Mac Osx 10.4 Tiger. without working DVD drive.

Comment: does OSx Tiger have bootcamp? If it does, I believe the older boot camp versions should allow you to install Ubuntu

Comment: No bootcamp came with 10.5. I am on an older version. 10.4

Comment: oh... well in that case I will try to see what I can find out for you, but if you want upgrade from tiger and it will get much easier.