# How to install Linux on old Mac X 10.4

Tags: macosx

I want to install a Linux on old Mac X 10.4, because this Snow Leopard that`s on the disk of this machine, is just obsolete. Please describe me this into step-by-step.

Comment: CPU? RAM? Please advise. Different versions of Ubuntu have different requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Make a LiveUSB for testing.

Get an ISO file for the standard Ubuntu with the GMOME3 desktop, or a 'flavour' of 18.04 or 19.10 with a different Desktop (generally less demanding of RAM and CPU). Download @  https://ubuntu.com/download/ or https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .The ISO used to make a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

Creating the LiveUSB, as per Canonical, Ubuntu's publishers, is typically done following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Once you make a LiveUSB, boot with it and test to ake sure it works OK, and that the desktop environment is suitable.

Once that's resolved, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.